# Converting a float to hours:minutes in Numbers

Tags: iwork, numbers, formatting

Probably this is a very easy thing to do, but as handicapped as I am using Apple's iWork applications, I just can't find it.

I have made a calculation in Numbers which results for example in 14,25 or 16,5. All I want to do is to have this output formatted in hours like 14:15 or 16:30.

I just can't find where to do it. I've tried to change the valuetype to 'duration' ('Duur' in Dutch). But that doesn't help. When I try to use =HOUR(value) it's not giving the correct output and it says the value is not a valid date.

Comment: Hmm - I've never had a problem by just adding units to the input times. Rather than forcing a float into a duration, have you tried adding units to the input cells? It's hard to guess what you're doing without seeing the spreadsheet to know if this would work though.

Comment: I see. I think its because of the calculation. Somehow still strange because its a bunch of numbers divided or and multiplied by eachother which result in a float. When I format a non-formula cell with 'duration' 4,5 becomes 4h 30m.

Comment: Seems like I have enough to try an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same thing to represent X seconds in a time format.

`=CONCATENATE(A0,"s")+"0s"` which `A0` is seconds

Answer (score 0):

Change the duration format to custom units.

This will take your decimal or `float` number and convert it to a duration.

`=DURATION(,,C8,,,)` where `C8` contains the floating point number placed into the `hours` location in the DURATION function.

In the **Inspector**, select the **Cell** tab and choose **Duration** under data format.  Choose **Custom Units**, select *hr* and *min* the using the dropdown for *Style* select `0:00`

---

[image: formula convert number to duration]

[image: Inspector date settings]